# JQuery selector: href attribute doesn't contain neither word1 nor word2

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm new to JQuery, i suppose that's really simple but I can't find the right selector. I tried with this code:

```
$(":not(a[href=word1],a[href=word2]").click(function() {
... do something
}
```

but it doesn't work, in fact it  seems to suck all the cpu time. Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's a much more efficient version that narrows it down to anchors first:

```
$("a:not([href*=word1],[href*=word2])").click(function() {
  //do something
});
```

[You can test the selector out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ACdWh/).

Currently you're trying to bind a `click` event to *everything* that's not an anchor with one of those words in it's `href` attribute...every element which is very expensive both to check *and* to bind, this instead binds to anchors and only then if their `href` doesn't contains either of those words.

Comment: great answer . save my more time .. thank you very much